# How to add decorations to tikz-qtree branches (for example, create AND-branches and OR-branches)?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-qtree

Suppose I want to show the expression

```
a IF b OR c
b IF d AND e
c IF f OR g
```

as a tree, using `tikz-qtree`. I'd want to do something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[grow'=right]
\tikzset{level distance=2cm}
\tikzset{sibling distance=1cm}
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={anchor=base west}}
\Tree[.a
         [.b
             [.d ]
             [.e ] ]
         [.c
             [.f ]
             [.g ] ] ]
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The above code generates the following tree:

[image: The resulting tree]

However, I'd like to include some decoration in the branches, showing that the first one (from a to b and c) is an "OR" branch, and that the others are one AND branch (from b) and one OR branch (from c). Something like a arc with a label, for example. I didn't find a way to do this in the tikz-qtree documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[grow'=right]
\tikzset{level distance=2cm}
\tikzset{sibling distance=1cm}
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={anchor=base west}}
\Tree[.\node (a) {a};
         [.\node (b) {b};
             [.\node (d) {d}; ]
             [.\node (e) {e}; ] ]
         [.\node (c) {c};
             [.\node (f) {f}; ]
             [.\node (g) {g}; ] ] ]
\node[red] at ($0.33*(a)+0.33*(b)+0.33*(c)$) {\textbf{OR}};
\node[red] at ($0.33*(b)+0.33*(d)+0.33*(e)$) {\textbf{AND}};
\node[red] at ($0.33*(c)+0.33*(f)+0.33*(g)$) {\textbf{OR}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I used the possibility to add named `nodes` in a qtree (see [the manual, section 4](http://www.isi.edu/~chiang/software/texmf/tikz-qtree-manual.pdf)). Then I used the `calc` library provided by `TikZ` to compute a coordiante "in the middle", which is basically the weighted average of the coordinates around it (with equal weights, thus `0.33`).

---

**Edit 1:** Here's a variant drawing an arc, it uses *Jasper Loy*'s answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15972/whats-the-easiest-way-to-draw-the-arc-defined-by-three-points-in-tikz):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all} 

\newcommand{\sparc}[8]% vertex, first child, last child, relative radius, text, text options, draw options, shift
{   \coordinate (firstarm) at ($(#1)!#4!(#2)$);
    \coordinate (lastarm) at ($(#1)!#4!(#3)$);
    \tkzDrawArc[#7](#1,lastarm)(firstarm)
    \node[#6] at ($(#1)+(#8)$) {#5};
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[grow'=right]
\tikzset{level distance=2cm}
\tikzset{sibling distance=1cm}
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={anchor=base west}}
\Tree[.\node (a) {a};
         [.\node (b) {b};
             [.\node (d) {d}; ]
             [.\node (e) {e}; ]
             [.\node (e2) {e$_2$}; ]
             [.\node (e3) {e$_3$}; ] ]
         [.\node (c) {c};
             [.\node (f) {f}; ]
             [.\node (g) {g}; ]
             [.\node (h) {h}; ] ] ]
\sparc{a}{b}{c}{0.7}{OR}{red}{ultra thick,color=blue!50!cyan}{1.5,0}
\sparc{b}{d}{e3}{0.6}{AND}{yellow,circle,fill=green!50!gray}{ultra thick,color=red!50!orange}{1,0}
\sparc{c}{f}{h}{0.6}{OR}{blue,circle,fill=blue!50!gray,fill opacity=0.3,text opacity=1}{ultra thick,color=green!30!gray}{1,0}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Edit 2:** the small gaps in the arcs are due to the fact that always  the `.center` of the nodes is used for computation. For a left-to right graph, this would be better:

```
\newcommand{\sparc}[8]% vertex, first child, last child, relative radius, text, text options, draw options, shift
{   \coordinate (firstarm) at ($(#1.east)!#4!(#2.west)$);
    \coordinate (lastarm) at ($(#1.east)!#4!(#3.west)$);
    \coordinate (vertex) at (#1.east);
    \tkzDrawArc[#7](vertex,lastarm)(firstarm)
    \node[#6] at ($(#1)+(#8)$) {#5};
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But I'd like something that would go across all branches from a node (if a node has three or five children, then putting a label as you showed may not look nice -- an arc going through the branches would be great)

Comment: this is great -- exactly what I needed, thank you!

Comment: One last observation: that code works when the size of the nodes above and below the arc are the same. If they're different, then their center will be at different places, and the arc will be longer at one of its sides. (I've made the nodes the same size, so I'm OK with it)