# TikZ: Draw angle to vector

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I need to draw a theta angle from the positive x-axis, going around counterclockwise until I find the FR vector. The code below is what I already knew how to do, but I'm having difficulty with this angle.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
    \draw[help lines, color=gray!30, dashed] (-4.9,-4.9) grid (4.9,4.9);
    \draw[->] (-5,0)--(5,0) node[right]{$x$};
    \draw[->] (0,-5)--(0,5) node[above]{$y$};
    \draw[blue,->,line width = 0.25mm] (0,0) -- (-2.7,-4.8)  node[left]{$FR$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: with the quotes library see the answer below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make use of the `fillbetween` library that comes with `pgfplots` (See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/239471/47927).

You need to name the paths of which you want to grab the intersections with `name path=`. Then you draw a new path with the option `intersection segments` and state the names of the pathes you previously assigned. You finally need to state which `sequence` you want to draw. `L1` here means that you want the first segment of the path that is on the left side of the `of` statement (which is `circ` here).

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
    \draw[help lines, color=gray!30, dashed] (-4.9,-4.9) grid (4.9,4.9);
    \draw[->] (-5,0)--(5,0) node[right]{$x$};
    \draw[->] (0,-5)--(0,5) node[above]{$y$};
    \draw[name path=fr, blue,->,line width = 0.25mm] (0,0) -- (-2.7,-4.8) node[left]{$FR$};
    
    \path[name path=circ] (0,0) circle (3);
    \draw[red, ->, intersection segments={of=circ and fr, sequence=L1}];
    \node[red] at (120:2.5) {$\theta$};
\end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles, quotes}
\begin{document}
    

    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
        \draw[help lines, color=gray!30, dashed] (-4.9,-4.9) grid (4.9,4.9);
        \draw[->] (-5,0)--(5,0) node[right,coordinate,label=right:$x$](x){};
        \draw[->] (0,-5)--(0,5) node[above]{$y$};
        \draw[blue,->,line width = 0.25mm] (0,0)coordinate(o) -- (-2.7,-4.8)  node[left, coordinate,label=below:$FR$](fr){};
        
        \pic[ draw,->,>=stealth,red!60!black, "$\theta_1$"{fill=white},inner sep=1pt, circle, angle eccentricity=1.1, angle radius = 10mm] {angle = x--o--fr};   
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is actually a better solution than mine. +1

Answer (score 1):

Using the [`tzplot`](https://ctan.org/pkg) package:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
    
\usepackage{tzplot}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tzhelplines(-4.9,-4.9)(4.9,4.9)
\tzaxes(-5,-5)(5,5){$x$}{$y$}
\tzcoors(0,0)(O)(-2.7,-4.8)(P);
% \theta
\tzline[blue,->,line width = 0.25mm](O)(P){$FR$}[l]
\tzanglemark[red,->](O-|1,0)(O)(P){$\theta$}[pos=.9](2cm)
% \theta_1
\tzline[->](O)(3,2)
\tzanglemark[red,->](O-|1,0)(O)(3,2){$\theta_1$}(8mm)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```