How to make vector function graphs
does anyone know how i can make a graph of a vector function like in this picture?

Welcome to TeX.SX! Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have. See minimal working example (MWE) for what needs to go into such a document.

Have a look at pgfplots

Something like https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/588985/36296 could be a starting point

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Here is a lazy way to do it.
Matching your missing MWE, a simple thing is missing here, too: the axes ... but that is no big deal.
1. class standalone
It will have some advantages, see e.g. this example.
2. arrow tips
You can switch to better tips via:
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
...
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
    >={Stealth},        % replace all tips
 ]

3. The curve
There are many ways to do it, e.g. you can use a parameter plot as you know from mathematics. Here I took a lazy path:

a simple line between the two endpoints \draw (.5,-.5) -- (1,.5);
is replaced by a Bezier curve, which is controlled by two control-points,
which I found easier to specify via polar coordinates (deg:radius)
\draw (.5,-.5) .. controls (95:4) and (-120:3) .. coordinate[pos=.5] (A)(1,.5);
BEFORE the end point I want to put a coordinate, where pos is the relative position along the curved path coordinate[pos=.5] (A)

4. The vector

draw a line from origin (0,0) to said point (A)
put a node before its endpoint, which contains the required text

\draw[->] (0,0) -- node[anchor=west,pos=.9] {$\vec{s}(t)$} 
                       (A);

5. Drawback from lazyness
As you can see, the control points widen the adaptable page size from standalone. So you may want to apply some clipping, if you follow this solution.


\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
    >={Stealth},
 ]
    \draw (.5,-.5) .. controls (95:4) and (-120:3) .. 
                coordinate[pos=.5] (A)(1,.5);
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- node[anchor=west,pos=.9] {$\vec{s}(t)$} 
                       (A);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

