Is there anyway to draw an arc from coordinates of two points, and its width?
First a minimal working sample is as follows.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}%

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (60:2) ++ (0,0) coordinate (A);%
\draw (A) arc (60:-60:2);%
\path (0:2) ++ (0,0) coordinate (D);%
\path (-60:2) ++ (0,0) coordinate (B);%
\draw [help lines, name path=patha] (A) -- (B);
\path [name path=pathb] (0,0) -- (2,0);
\path[name intersections={of=patha and pathb, by={C}}];%
\draw [help lines] (C) -- (D);
\node [left] at (A) {$A$};
\node [left] at (B) {$B$};
\node [left] at (C) {$C$};
\node [right] at (D) {$D$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


As you see, I draw an arc ADB from one coordinate, its start angle and end angle, and its radius. My question is
Is there anyway to draw an arc from coordinates of two points, e.g., A and B, and its width, e.g., CD=1? (suppose the arc faces to the left or the other directions)

Does that specify a unique arc?

@cfr I think so provided the arc faces to the left side or the other directions. Suppose the width of the arc is a, the radius is r, the vertical coordinates of the two points are y, z, then (r-x)^2+(y-z)^2/4=r^2, and hence r could be worked out.

OK. So rule out it flipping. Then you mean (r-a)^2+(y-z)^2/4=r^2? (There's no a in your equation.)

@cfr (r-a)^2 ? Aha?

If I've understood the problem correctly, it's like drawing a circular arc through 3 points, isn't it? What's the easiest way to draw the arc defined by three points in TikZ?

You said the width was a but had x in the equation ....

There are already several solutions to this kind of geometric problems: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15972/whats-the-easiest-way-to-draw-the-arc-defined-by-three-points-in-tikz .
